# Magnetic field perceived by the electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-spin, hamiltonian, hydrogen

> This section presents a relatively simple and quantitative description of the spin-orbit interaction for an electron bound to a hydrogen-like atom, up to first order in perturbation theory, using some semiclassical electrodynamics and non-relativistic quantum mechanics. This gives results that agree reasonably well with observations.

> The energy of a magnetic moment in a magnetic field is given by
> $$\Delta {\rm H}_{}=-{\boldsymbol \mu }\cdot \mathbf {B}$$
> where $\boldsymbol \mu$ is the magnetic moment of the particle, and $\bf B$ is the magnetic field it experiences.

> We shall deal with the magnetic field first. Although in the rest frame of the nucleus, there is no magnetic field acting on the electron, there *is* one in the rest frame of the electron. Ignoring for now that this frame is not inertial, in SI units we end up with the equation
> $${ \mathbf {B} =-{\frac {\mathbf {v} \times \mathbf {E} }{c^{2}}}}$$

Now, my professor is used to work with the $\bf H$-field instead of $\bf B$, and in CGS units. So the previous formula becomes:
$${\bf H} = \frac 1 2 \frac {\boldsymbol {\cal E} \ \times \bf v}{c}$$
The problem is that $\frac 1 2 $ factor. He said it's the famous *Thomas factor*... can someone relate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1/2  is an effect due to [Thomas  precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_precession). The Wiki linked article has a good exposition.  See also [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0310016) for a pedagogical account.